# How to change a instance of the class, from inside another instance

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm studying python and came across this problem that I am trying to solve. It probably has an easy solution that I still didn't learn or couldn't find.
I have this class named Category with a method to make a deposit, a withdraw and a transfer, that writes this operations to a list called ledger.
I instantiate the Category class as food, and make a deposit and two withdraws, and it worked fine. Then I create a new instance of the Category class called clothing, but when I try to make a transfer from the food ledger to the clothing ledger, I can't do it. It makes the withdraw from the food ledger, that part works, but when I try to make a deposit to the clothing ledger, the deposit gets made to the same food ledger instead.
What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

```
class Category:
    ledger = list()
    category_name = ''
    def __init__(self, category):
        self.category_name = category

    def deposit(self, amount, description=''):
        entry = dict()
        entry['amount'] = amount
        entry['description'] = description
        self.ledger.append(entry)

    def withdraw(self, amount, description=''):
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            entry = dict()
            entry['amount'] = -abs(amount)
            entry['description'] = description
            self.ledger.append(entry)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def transfer(self, amount, to_category):
        if self.check_funds(amount):
            self.withdraw(amount, "Transfer to " + to_category.category_name)
            to_category.deposit(amount, 'Transfer from ' + self.category_name)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_balance(self):
        balance = 0
        for entry in self.ledger:
            balance = balance + entry.get('amount')
        return balance

    def check_funds(self, amount):
        if self.get_balance() >= amount:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        


def create_spend_chart(categories):
    categories = categories


food = Category("Food")
food.deposit(1000, "initial deposit")
food.withdraw(10.15, "groceries")
food.withdraw(15.89, "restaurant and more food for dessert")
clothing = Category("Clothing")
food.transfer(50, clothing)
# clothing.withdraw(25.55)
# clothing.withdraw(100)
```

Comment: You have `ledger` as a class attribute, meaning it belongs to _every_ instance, not just `food` or `clothing`. Place it inside your `__init__` method like `self.ledger = list()`.